# How does Twitter Format their Weekly Summary Email and how to format those tweets in email in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, twitter

I am having a twitter application,according to my application, I wanted to send tweets to the user's email address daily who are using my website. But the problem is tweets are not formatted in proper twitter format. I wanted to send them tweets in a mail same as we get a mail from twitter at the end of the week(Here's what's trending on Twitter this week.) Embedding tweet is not working, since javascript is not working.

See attached image[image]

Comment: I don't get that email, include it in your question.  You just like the styling of the email?

Comment: @Anthony see attached image.. yes styling plus adding links for retweet,reply and favorites